# ASP -Set Current Date and time

Tags: asp.net

When I run the ASP project in local host, show correct local time **(Sri Lanka)** . But when host the project show incorrect date, Time..

```
lable_date_time.Text = string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
```

Hosting server in **United states** ([www.smarterasp.net](https://www.smarterasp.net))

How to Fix it?
Thank You...

Comment: It uses the timezone of the local machine: your own timezone when you run locally, the server's timezone or possibly UTC when installed on some server.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it programatically?

Comment: [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) can handle timezones. The site contains sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the FindSystemTimeZoneById method useful, along with ConvertTimeFromUtc method. Both are methods of the System.TimeZoneInfo class. Example I used to pass the time in a time zone passed in from a user and converting that to stock market time in NYC. After you do the calculation you can adjust by getting the difference of the offset:

```
TimeZoneInfo tradeTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tradeTimeZone);
var tradetz = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(myexactexetime, tradeTimeZoneInfo);

TimeZoneInfo nyTZI = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var marketTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeInUsersZone, nyTZI);

TimeSpan diff = marketTimezone - tradetz;
double hours = diff.TotalHours;
dateTimeInUsersZone= dateTimeInUsersZone.AddHours(hours);
```